# Can't get SVG USE to load in plunkr

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I'm trying to demonstrate an edge case issue in isolation, where svg's use tag will not load the external asset from an href under certain conditions.

I'm trying to run this in plunkr to share my problem and look for a solution but cannot get the image to load *at all* with an `<use>` tag.

Below is my code from the angular template:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  focusable="false"
  [attr.height]="height"
  [attr.width]="width"
  [attr.viewbox]="viewbox">

  <use #use
    [attr.viewbox]="viewbox"
    attr.href="{{ path || 'icon.svg' }}"
    attr.width="100%"
    attr.height="100%">
  </use>
</svg>
```

and `icon.svg` is posted below:

```
<svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L2 22l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-7 9h-2V5h2v6zm0 4h-2v-2h2v2z"/>
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

How can I show an svg using `<svg><use href="…">` on plunkr?

Is this an issue?
Have I misunderstood how to use `<use>`?

https://embed.plnkr.co/TW7yM6EIW7PoFyKyudvE/

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: Apologies, I edited to show the most relevant parts of the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

`<use>` elements cannot point to a complete svg file, they need to point to some element within that file.

> [Unlike ‘image’, the ‘use’ element cannot reference entire files.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)

Comment: Well, that was unexpected. Thanks for the point in the right direction. Now my angular code works flawlessly and I cannot recreate the problem! haha.